# SerialPort in WPF threw I/O Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am work on a very simple program (C# WPF application in VS2010) that display data from SerialPort and display on a TextBox. The program works fine in normal circumstances. But when user open a connection, collect some data, close it, and open it again, and do this for several cycles, the program will eventually throw an exception:

**"The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."**
[The I/O Exception occurred in the ReadLine()]

Sometime the program would throw me an exception; sometimes the program just hangs.
Below is my code:

```
/* Click to Open ComPort */
private void PortOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
        serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        serialPort1.Open();

        serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Receive);
    }
}

/* Receive data from ComPort */
private void Receive(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            string1 = serialPort1.ReadLine(); /* This is where I/O Exception occurred */
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUiTextDelegate(DisplayText), string1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void DisplayText(string string1)
{
    textBox1.Text = string1;
}
/* Close ComPort */
private void PortClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        serialPort1.Close();
    }            
}
```

Following summarize my head-banging-against-table attempts in the past 40 hours which result in no progress:

1. I have tried add `Thread.Sleep(3000)` before and after `Open()` and `Close()`. And I start to get so frustrated that I put `Thread.Sleep` in between every single line. I though that would allow enough time for some unfinished working in the background. Doesn't solve the problem.
2. I tried [Zach Saw's Post](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html). A lot of comments left on the blog post are very positive. I tried the approach and even copy and paste the exact code to mine. Doesn't solve the problem. A very long post that wasted half of my day.
3. Kim Hamilton address the issues [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-_5b00_kim-hamilton_5d00_.aspx). which suggest using `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`. Tried and still persist the same problem.
4. There was a very nice commercial SerialPort library [Franson SerialTools](http://franson.com/serialtools/) which is fairly cheap and works fantastic with no bugs regardless of how many time and how quick I Open() or Close() the serialPort. However, they have discontinue their development and the library they have only works on Form application, not WPF. Some of their argument in their API only accepts Forms.Control. too bad. There are other Commercial product out there but either they are overly priced or do not offer free trail so I wouldn't know whether it works or not before purchase

Does anyone get the .NET SerialPort to work and actually check for bugs (Open() and Close() many times - even when there are no incoming data)?

Comment: The MSDN documentation hints that you should not place a blocking read in the event handler with this statement, "Only one event handler can execute at a time."  I highly recommend that you don't use ReadLine in the handler.

Comment: @dbasnett, good point, I think I will need to create a Thread that does the job and Join/Close as it close?

Comment: Why not read the bytes that are available, and queue those byte for processing by another thread?  This approach will require that you detect newline manually.

Comment: @dbasnett, I am already using newline currently. "queue thos bytes for processing by another thread" I don't know how to do. Do you mean doing a While Thread.Start() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open port you add event handler, when closing i think you should remove it.

Try to do this:

```
private void PortClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        serialPort1.DataReceived -= Receive;
        serialPort1.Close();
    }            
}
```

Hope this solves problem.

Comment: as simple as your solution, it solved my problem. You save my weekend of banging heads, wish there's more upvote to offer. I am curious why ReadLine() is still reading while I call close? And I have to remove the event to avoid it..

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, DataReceived is already running when the exception is thrown.

Comment: So thats why you need to remove handler before close.

Comment: @Hans Passant, strange enough I tried Reniuz code and it actually work for me. No more I/O Exception. However, though I felt there should be a more proper way to do it - removing an event feels like a hack?

Comment: @KMC take a look at code from example in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline.aspx) its without event.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the blocking call to `ReadLine` is interrupted by a call to `Close` from the UI thread. What's wrong with catching this error? I would expect it to happen.

Comment: yes you are right the ReadLine() is interrupting the Close(). So what am I supposed to do? I tried putting the thread to sleep after ReadLine and before Close. no success still.

Comment: maybe add variable bool isClosing, check it in `if(serialPort1.IsOpen && !isClosing)` and set isClosing = true when button clicked?

Comment: @Reniuz, sounded like a nice trick. I tried it gave me I/O Exception on the same line, the difference is: "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."

Answer (score 0):

@Reniuz solution didn't help me also.
Actually I couldn't understand how it could help at all, obviously as @Hans Passant comment, the DataReceived could be already in progress while unsubscribing the event.
My solution for this was to unsubscribe within the DataReceived event, just raise a flag whenever unsubscribe is needed and check for it in the DataReceived event.

```
public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
// Brief:   Handle data received event
{
  // Read the data
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  // Check for unsubscribe
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  if (bStopDataRequested)
  {
    serialPort1.DataReceived -= DataReceivedHandler;  // Unsubscribe to DataReceived event

    // Only then close the port
  }
}
```